# how do i get my wordpress website url with Colon ':' ..?

Tags: php, wordpress, url, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

```
add_action( 'init', function() {

    add_shortcode( 'site_url', function( $atts = null, $content = null ) {
        return site_url();
    });

});
```

I'm Using The Short Code **[`site_url`]** and My Short Code Function Returned `https//shad-pro.com/contact-us`

How Do I get The Proper `Url` With Colon **`:`**

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3xwL.png)

Answer (score 0):

First: Why do you create an add_action to init to make a shortcode?

Second, the function site_url () is deprecated by Wordpress for its native function home_url ().

Try to correct the code as follows:

```
function create_site_url()
{
    return home_url();
}

add_shortcode('site_url', 'create_site_url');
```

home_url() reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/home_url

add_shortcode() reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode

Comment: _Here is The Code Which I Tried.._

Comment: `function url_shortcode() { `
` return get_bloginfo('url'); `
`}`
`add_shortcode('url','url_shortcode');`

Comment: get_bloginfo ('url') returns what you have set in Wordpress settings, but if you want to pass additional parameters it is preferable to use home_url (). Example: https://www.yoursite.com/contacts/ = home_url ('contacts');

Comment: I Understand You But My Main Problem is the URL is escaping The colon **`:`** I have The Code Of Getting The Url.

Comment: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3xwL.png] **`Image Link`** I tried Your Code but Link Is Generated Without The Colon As You Can See In The Image....

Comment: I took a look at your site. Every page outside the homepage returns an error 500 Internal Server. Usually it happens when the permalinks have not been created. This can cause address malfunctions. Try to regenerate the permalinks through the panel: Setting-> permalink, and then check in general setting if your url contains colum (:)

Comment: I Checked My Website Url in General Settings The Url Has The **`:`** & I'm Using The Post Name In Permalinks Setting..

Comment: Your Right Every page Outside the home Page return 500 Internal server error But when i set my permalink from plain to post name it doesn't return 500 internal error.